# Multiple inheritance with one ancestor inheriting std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++

Imagine a scenario when a class `D` inherits from multiple ancestors `A`, `B`, `C` and has to be able to obtain a shared pointer to itself (`shared_from_this()`). If one of the ancestors, say B, already inherits `std::enable_shared_from_this<B>`, is it enough to provide `shared_from_this` functionality for `D`?

Consider the following code as an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class A 
{
public:
    void printX() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
protected:
    A(int x) : x{ x } {}    
private:
    int x{ 3 };
};

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
public:
    void printY() { std::cout << y << std::endl; }
protected:
    B(double y) : y{ y } {}
private:
    double y{ 5.89 };
};

class C
{
public:
    void printS() { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
protected:
    C(const std::string& s) : s{ s } {} 
private:
    std::string s{ "just a test" };
};

class D : public A, public B, public C
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<D> create(std::size_t n)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<D> dptr{ new D(1, 3.14, "parent node") };
        
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            dptr->addChild(std::shared_ptr<D>{ new D(2, 7.7, "child node") });

        return dptr;
    }

    ~D()
    {
        std::cout << "~D()" << std::endl;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<D> getChild(std::size_t index) const
    {
        return children.at(index);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<D> getParent() const
    {
        return parent.lock();
    }

protected:
    D(int x, double y, const std::string& s)
        : A{ x }, B{ y }, C{ s } { }

    void addChild(const std::shared_ptr<D>& child)
    {
        child->parent = std::static_pointer_cast<D>(shared_from_this());
        children.push_back(child);
    }

private:
    std::weak_ptr<D> parent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<D>> children;
};


int main()
{
    auto dptr = D::create(3);

    auto child1 = dptr->getChild(1);
    auto parent = child1->getParent();
    assert(parent == dptr);

    parent->printX();
    parent->printY();
    parent->printS();
}
```

I didn't notice any issues with the code above, but when I read other questions on StackOverflow regarding `std::enable_shared_from_this` and multiple inheritance, I see people using various kinds of tricks to make it work. So I was not quite sure if my code using a simple type cast is safe.

Comment: When creating code like this you really have to ask yourself, is std::shared_ptr (shared ownership) really the model that is needed? In general I can get away with a datastructure being the sole owner of things (and managing the life cycle of that) and handing out references for the duration of calls. (pretty much like std::vector's index or at methods).  The only time I really need shared ownership is if I cannot control the lifetime of objects explicitly (like when two threads need access to shared data).

Comment: @PepijnKramer Typically I prefer parent-child paradigm too, but I wanted to avoid mixing raw pointers with smart pointers in the same project, which heavily relies on shared pointers.

Comment: Raw pointers are okay, as long as they are non-owning (even then I prefer using references when objects must be valid).  See [F.7: For general use, take T* or T& arguments rather than smart pointers](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f7-for-general-use-take-t-or-t-arguments-rather-than-smart-pointers).  Passing a shared_ptr by reference of value to a function is just overhead.  I realy object to `addChild(const std;:shared_ptr`.  Data structure D should either take ownership (unique_ptr) or it  does not (raw pointer/reference).

Comment: And yes I know... sometimes you can be bound by existing (sub-optimal) desings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is legal, as long as there is only a single publicly accessible instance of `enable_shared_from_this` in the inheritance hierarchy.

Most of the workarounds and tricks are when you want to have multiple bases which each inherit from `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: Also note that the first instance must be created using std::make_shared, you can't use shared_from_this if the class is created in any other way.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Actually, you can also pass it to the `shared_ptr` constructor.  But it must have been inserted into a `shared_ptr` at some point prior to calling `shared_from_this()`